# Regarding MFC Property sheet

Tags: mfc

I have two queries.

Is there any way to disable the traverse to other property pages when I am working on one page in MFC ?

Is there any way to go to the next page of the property sheet on click of a button in the current page in MFC ?

Comment: It seems you are trying to re-invent [Property Sheets as Wizards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z4twbax.aspx).

Comment: Your description is vague. What property sheet class are you using? CPropertySheet, CMFCPropertySheet, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to disable the traverse to other property pages when
>   I am working on one page in MFC ?

respond to the [PSN_KILLACTIVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774559(v=vs.85).aspx) message and return TRUE

MFC equivalent: [OnKillActive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2122ct0z(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Is there any way to go to the next page of the property sheet on click
>   of a button in the current page in MFC ?

send a [PSM_PRESSBUTTON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774597(v=vs.85).aspx) message with wParam as `PSBTN_NEXT`

MFC equivalent: [PressButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4edy8fcx(v=vs.100).aspx), like `PressButton(PSBTN_NEXT)`

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
CMyPropertySheet::DisableNextButton()
{
    SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_BACK);
}

CMyPropertySheet::EnableNextButton()
{
    SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_BACK | PSWIZB_NEXT);
}
```

I'm not sure, if this makes the button invisible. Maybe `SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_DISABLEDFINISH)` will also disable the next button, if the finish button isn't yet reached.

2.

```
CMyPropertySheet::GoToNextPage()
{
    PressButton(PSBTN_NEXT);
}
```